# Unable to unload Assembly and unsure why

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

**Update:** I've managed to get this into WinDbg and take a look at what's going on.  I found two things: first, this list wasn't getting released properly:

```
private Stack<DependencyAssemblyLoadContext> _loadedContexts;
```

So I nulled that out, moved around my `GC` calls a bit (bad practice I know, but hey, it's just a POC/demo.  I can worry about doing it better later.), and one of my two sample DLLs unloaded.  (I also turned a few lists into stacks to I could try to get them nulled out as soon as possible.  Again, jumping through hoops so I can demo the concept to people.)

The other thing I noticed, though, was that one sample task (which throws an exception) was sticking around.  WinDbg yielded the following:

```
0:009> !gcroot -all 0000025e8fc0ffa8
Thread 5824:
    000000F0F237E5F0 00007FFDC9361EAE CleanupService.NetCore.Program.Run() [C:\stuff\Program.cs @ 69]
        rbp-b0: 000000f0f237e630
            ->  0000025E8FC12CB0 System.NotImplementedException
            ->  0000025E8FC16230 System.Object[]
            ->  0000025E8FC0FFA8 System.Reflection.LoaderAllocator

    000000F0F237E5F0 00007FFDC9361EAE CleanupService.NetCore.Program.Run() [C:\stuff\Program.cs @ 69]
        rbp-88: 000000f0f237e658
            ->  0000025E8FC111C8 System.RuntimeType
            ->  0000025E8FC0FFA8 System.Reflection.LoaderAllocator

    000000F0F237E5F0 00007FFDC9361EAE CleanupService.NetCore.Program.Run() [C:\stuff\Program.cs @ 69]
        rbp-78: 000000f0f237e668
            ->  0000025E8FC11268 CleanupService.Sample.SimpleFailedTask
            ->  0000025E8FC0FFA8 System.Reflection.LoaderAllocator
```

If I'm reading that right, the exception itself is staying in memory?  And since it comes from a class that is in an assembly that is trying to be unloaded, the assembly doesn't unload.

This seems... odd.  How can I get rid of the exception reference?

Original description of the problem follows, but I have updated the code below.

---

I have a POC for a system that scans a bunch of DLLs, loads tasks from them, and then unloads them.  This is .NET Core 3.0, so I'm using the `AssemblyLoadContext`.  I have everything loading ok, and the `Unloading` event fires off, but when I watch my Modules window the DLLs stay loaded.  This contrasts with an `AppDomain`-based CLR version, where the DLLs unload from the Modules window the moment the domain is ripped down.

I think I have a reference to something somewhere, but I can't figure out where, and WinDbg is... iffy, due to corporate restrictions on admin rights.

**Main app:**

```
private IFileSystemService _fileSystemService;
private ITaskManagementService _taskManagementService;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().Run();
}

public Program()
{
    _fileSystemService = new FileSystemService();
    _taskManagementService = new TaskManagementService();
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public void Run()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Getting available files...");
    var files = _fileSystemService.GetFilePaths("*.dll");
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {files.Length} files to scan.");

    Console.WriteLine("Scanning for tasks...");
    var tasks = _taskManagementService.GetAvailableCleanupTasks(files);
    Console.WriteLine($"Total tasks found: { tasks.Count() }");

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var task = tasks.Pop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Executing task: { task.GetType().Name }");
        Console.WriteLine("Output:");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        try
        {
            task.Execute<object>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex = null;
            continue;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            task = null;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up... ");
    _taskManagementService.UnloadAssemblies();
    _taskManagementService = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Cleanup done.");

    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    Console.WriteLine("Process complete.  Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**And here's the `TaskManagementService`, which loads and unloads Assemblies:**

```
private Stack<DependencyAssemblyLoadContext> _loadedContexts;

public TaskManagementService()
{
    _loadedContexts = new Stack<DependencyAssemblyLoadContext>();
}

public Stack<ICleanupTask> GetAvailableCleanupTasks(string[] assemblyPaths)
{
    // This application is designed to run every 24 hours, so just unload what we have before reloading
    UnloadAssemblies();

    var results = new Stack<ICleanupTask>();

    // Loads the assembly containing the task loader so it can be used.  The assembly also contains ICleanupTask and CleanupTask.
    foreach (var path in assemblyPaths)
    {
        var context = new DependencyAssemblyLoadContext(path);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
        var assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);

        foreach (var task in GetTasksFromAssembly(assembly))
        {
            results.Push(task);
        }

        _loadedContexts.Push(context);
    }

    return results;
}

public void UnloadAssemblies()
{
    if (_loadedContexts.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    while (_loadedContexts.Count > 0)
    {
        var context = _loadedContexts.Pop();
        // context.Unloading += (e) => Console.WriteLine($"Assembly {e.Assemblies.First().GetName()} unloading...");
        context.Unload();
        context = null;
    }
}

private List<ICleanupTask> GetTasksFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
{
    var tasks = new List<ICleanupTask>();

    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CleanupTask)))
        {
            tasks.Add(CreateTask(type));
        }
    }

    return tasks;
}

private ICleanupTask CreateTask(Type taskType)
{
    return (ICleanupTask)Activator.CreateInstance(taskType);
}
```